# Using PredicateBuilder with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda, predicatebuilder

I have recreated the Predicatebuilder class in a seperate C# project and I'm trying to use it in a VB.NET project but I keep getting the following error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Or' accepts this number of arguments.

when I use it like so:

```
Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.False(Of t_Quote)()
predicate = predicate.Or(Function(q) q.iQuoteType = iQuoteType)
```

The relivant project is referenced, I'm using the correct imports statement and it all compiles without any errors.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Here is the PredicateBuilder class in C# I'm using:

> public static class PredicateBuilder
>       {
>           public static Expression> True() {
>   return f => true; }
>           public static Expression> False() {
>   return f => false; }
>
> ```
>     public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this
> ```
>
> Expression> expr1,
>                                                               Expression> expr2)
>           {
>               var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2,
>   expr1.Parameters.Cast());
>               return Expression.Lambda>
>                      (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body,
>   invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
>           }
>
> ```
>     public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this
> ```
>
> Expression> expr1,
>                                                               Expression> expr2)
>           {
>               var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2,
>   expr1.Parameters.Cast());
>               return Expression.Lambda>
>                      (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body,
>   invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
>           }
>       }

Comment: Without knowing your own API, its impossible to give an answer to this question. Post the C# version of the code, or post the signature to the PredicateBuilder.Or method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue. It was because Option Infer was set to Off. As soon as I set it to On the correct type was infered and it all worked as it should.

Comment: Make sure you set this as the accepted answer, as it's useful information for others to know!

Answer (score 9):

Here's the code that works for me in VB.NET, as I also tweaked this class to run in VB.NET...

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Public Module PredicateBuilder
    Public Function [True](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return Function(f) True
    End Function

    Public Function [False](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return Function(f) False
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [Or](Of T)(ByVal expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
        Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[Or](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [And](Of T)(ByVal expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
        Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[And](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
    End Function
End Module
```

And here's how I use it:

```
Dim pred = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyClass)()

pred = pred.And(Function(m As MyClass) m.SomeProperty = someValue)
pred = pred.Or(Function(m As MyClass) m.SomeProperty = someValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to bear in mind, though it may not solve your particular issue, is case-sensitivity when working with cross-language solutions.

C# and the CLR itself are case-sensitive; VB.NET is not. Depending on which way you're consuming the library, an exception may be thrown because the case does not match (and therefore fails to resolve to a known type).

This can happen if you think you've consistently declared your namespace names, but one class has the namespace declared with *one* character in upper case. This is very easy to do in Visual Basic, but to VB.NET, they all look like they've compiled down to a single, cohesive namespace. As far as the CLR is concerned though, they are two distinct namespaces.

I've run into this issue before, and it was a *very* elusive bug to track down.

I know you're consuming a C# project from VB.NET, but keep an eye out for those types of issues.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.False(Of Integer)()
predicate = predicate.Or(Function(q) q Mod 2 = 0)
```

(I don't have your `t_Quote` type)

Also, it's horrible practice to have a type name like `t_Quote`.  That should be called `Quote`; Hungarian notation and underscores are both frowned upon in C# names.

Comment: I accept your comment on the naming convention (not my choice!). The t_Quote type is a linq to sql class does that information help with this issue?