# Building a dynamic LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, custom-linq-providers

I have a listbox which users can select from a list if Towns, I want to be able to build a LINQ query based on the selected items in the list e.g.

```
Dim ddlTowns As ListBox = CType(Filter_Accommodation1.FindControl("ddlTowns"), ListBox)
        If Not ddlTowns Is Nothing Then
            For Each Item In ddlTowns.Items
                If Item.Selected Then
                    '// Build query
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

I have researched LinqKit as it appears to be able to do what I need but I cannot after hours of trying make any headway. I cannot find anything in VB which translates in anything meaningful or usable.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a Eureka moment and rather than using predicate I came up with this...

```
Private Function Filter_Accommomdation_QueryBuilder() As IEnumerable

            Dim ddlTowns As ListBox = CType(Filter_Accommodation1.FindControl("ddlTowns"), ListBox)
            Dim myList As New List(Of String)
            If Not ddlTowns Is Nothing Then
                For Each Item In ddlTowns.Items
                    If Item.Selected Then
                        myList.Add(Item.value)
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            Dim Filter_Query = _
                       From c In InitialQuery _
                       Where myList.ToArray.Contains(c.MyData.element("townvillage").value) _
                       Select c
            Return Filter_Query


        End Function
```

As a note I'm using c.MyData as the nature of InitialQuery demands a number of structured fields (the query is reused from  various tables which by poor design aren't very consistant).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question - contains some useful VB examples for you: [Using PredicateBuilder with VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506771/using-predicatebuilder-with-vb-net)