# Constructing dynamic lambda

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Using EF6 + SQL Server 2008 R2 + .NET Fx 4.5.

I need to search a particular string in multiple fields of my entity and its related entities and return the records where the search string is found in ANY of the fields. Here's the relevant code:

```
Dim Query = MyDB.items.AsQueryable()

Query = Query.Where(Function(r) _
                              r.stock_no.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
                              r.serial_number.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
                              r.catalog_item.description.Contains(searchString) OrElse _                                 r.catalog_item.category.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
                              r.item_status.name.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
                              r.notes.Contains(searchString))

If r.issued_to_company_id.HasValue Then 'This is a nullable field (0-1 relation)
    Query = Query.OR_FUNCTION(Function(r) r.issued_to_company.name.Contains(searchString))
End If
```

The problem is that there is no **OR_FUNCTION** in LINQ. You can simulate an optional **AND_FUNCTION** by calling another `Where` on the `Query` object, but I need to do OR here.

I have tried to use `If` and `IIf` inside the predicate too, but seemingly can't do that without introducing a compile- or run-time error. What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

**First Way**

The tricky way would be to use the logic rule of `A OR B` equals `NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)`:

```
' Assuming QueryAll holds all values
Query = QueryAll.Where(Function(r) _ 
                              Not r.stock_no.Contains(searchString) Andalso _
                              Not r.serial_number.Contains(searchString) Andalso _
                              Not r.catalog_item.description.Contains(searchString) Andalso _                                  Not r.catalog_item.category.Contains(searchString) Andalso _
                              Not r.item_status.name.Contains(searchString) Andalso _
                              Not r.notes.Contains(searchString))

' Query will hold all rows which DO NOT contain searchString.
Query = Query.Where(Function(r) Not r.issued_to_company.name.Contains(searchString))
' Here you should choose all elements in QueryAll which are not in Query. 
' The result would be all rows containing searchString.
```

**Second Way**

What about building a `predicate` using `PredicateBuilder` and than use it in your Where clause?

```
Dim pred = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyClass)()    
pred = pred.And(Function(m As MyClass) m.SomeProperty = someValue)
pred = pred.Or(Function(m As MyClass) m.SomeProperty = someValue)
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506771/using-predicatebuilder-with-vb-net).

**Third Way**

Another possible way is by using [Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any 3rd-party libraries. This is pretty basic problem and should be solvable within the bounds of framework. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for (Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx

Comment: Another way is to make some logical tricks. Like: NOT(NOT(A) AND NOT(B)) equals (A OR B). So just make your first statement with Not() and in the () put all elements with Not x.Contains("some string"). See the edited answer.

Comment: These are really good suggestions. I figured out another, somewhat simpler way of doing this. See my answer below. +1 for the great tricks.

Comment: @dotNet, about your answer: I think the `True` in the `IF` statement should be `False`, shouldn't it? And another thing: If your goal is to make extra different calls to `Query.Where` - can it be done your way?

Comment: Correct. Thanks for pointing out. And yes to your second question. The whole `If` clause acts as a boolean expression, so you could append as many of them as you like using `OrElse`.

Comment: In **ANOTHER** `Where' ??

Answer (score 1):

Found it. You can actually use the new inline `If` syntax to include optional `Or` into the above query. Just like this:

```
Query = Query.Where(Function(r) _
           r.stock_no.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           r.serial_number.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           r.catalog_item.description.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           r.catalog_item.category.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           r.item_status.name.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           r.notes.Contains(searchString) OrElse _
           If(r.catalog_item.manufacturer_id.HasValue, r.catalog_item.manufacturer_company.name.Contains(searchString), True))
```

Note that this works with `Option Strict` on, i.e. `If` can infer the type of return value as boolean. @ilanS's answers are good too, but this one seems simpler and more natural.